# How can I absolute a position on a h1 in sm or md view when it has a fixed position in md or lg view bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I have half of the page with an h1 (fixed position) and the other col empty. As I scroll down the col moves up the h1 stays fixed... how can I get the h1 to go in an absolute position when switching to a sml or md size screen. I Have this ....

```
<section id="header">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row height align-items-center">
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center position-fixed">
    <h1>My h1 title</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- empty column to the right, scroll down -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you want to use these classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#common-values only on sm and md screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css file you can use the [@media rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) you can see the width of the different bootstrap col sizes.

so in your case 720px for the md is what you want. So this might be the code to put in your css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    h1 {
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach worked thank you so much. I actually had to add two @media and got rid of my position-fixed in my html.